# Hibernate validator, weblogic 12c: ClassCastException when validating Spring MVC mapping input

Tags: spring-mvc, weblogic, weblogic12c, hibernate-validator

I have spring boot web application which is deployed to Weblogic 12c container.

I have spring MVC mapping `processEvent(@Valid @RequestBody UpstreamEvent event)`

My `weblogic.xml` file contains:

```
<container-descriptor>
    <prefer-web-inf-classes>false</prefer-web-inf-classes>
    <prefer-application-packages>
        <package-name>com.google.*</package-name>
        <package-name>javax.persistence.*</package-name>
        <package-name>javax.persistence.spi*</package-name>
        <package-name>org.apache.commons.*</package-name>
        <package-name>org.hibernate.*</package-name>
        <package-name>javax.validation.*</package-name>
        <package-name>org.jboss.logging.*</package-name>
        <package-name>com.fasterxml.classmate.*</package-name>
        <package-name>org.joda.*</package-name>
        <package-name>org.springframework.*</package-name>
        <package-name>org.slf4j.*</package-name>
        <package-name>ch.qos.logback.*</package-name>
        <package-name>org.objectweb.asm.*</package-name>
        <package-name>antlr.*</package-name>
        <package-name>javassist.*</package-name>
    </prefer-application-packages>
</container-descriptor>
```

When the request comes in, input gets validated and I am getting exceptions as follows:

```
17-10-23 18:39:03.930 [[ACTIVE] ExecuteThread: '0' for queue: 'weblogic.kernel.Default (self-tuning)'] ERROR o.springframework.boot.web.support.ErrorPageFilter [] - Forwarding to error page from request [/api/playground/process-event] due to exception [HV000041: Call to TraversableResolver.isReachable() threw an exception.]
javax.validation.ValidationException: HV000041: Call to TraversableResolver.isReachable() threw an exception.
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.isReachable(ValidatorImpl.java:1652)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.isValidationRequired(ValidatorImpl.java:1628)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateMetaConstraint(ValidatorImpl.java:612)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraint(ValidatorImpl.java:583)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForSingleDefaultGroupElement(ValidatorImpl.java:527)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForDefaultGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:495)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateConstraintsForCurrentGroup(ValidatorImpl.java:460)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validateInContext(ValidatorImpl.java:410)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.validate(ValidatorImpl.java:207)
    at org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.SpringValidatorAdapter.validate(SpringValidatorAdapter.java:118)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcValidator.validate(WebMvcValidator.java:69)
    at org.springframework.validation.DataBinder.validate(DataBinder.java:891)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.validateIfApplicable(AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver.java:270)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.resolveArgument(RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor.java:133)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.resolveArgument(HandlerMethodArgumentResolverComposite.java:121)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.getMethodArgumentValues(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:158)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:128)


Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider cannot be cast to javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider
    at javax.persistence.Persistence$1.isLoaded(Persistence.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.isReachable(JPATraversableResolver.java:47)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver.DefaultTraversableResolver.isReachable(DefaultTraversableResolver.java:128)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.resolver.CachingTraversableResolverForSingleValidation.isReachable(CachingTraversableResolverForSingleValidation.java:36)
    at org.hibernate.validator.internal.engine.ValidatorImpl.isReachable(ValidatorImpl.java:1643)
    ... 104 common frames omitted
```

It seems it is some classpath problem, even though I preferred hibernate validator and its dependencies.

I don't see these exceptions when my app is deployed to Tomcat.

Why am I getting the exception?

Answer (score 1):

For me I got it working by adding the following in weblogic.xml

```
<wls:prefer-application-resources>
<wls:resource-name>META-INF/services/javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider</wls:resource-name>
</wls:prefer-application-resources>
```